# Interchange the axes in R and count number of dates in a list in R

Tags: r, date, count, plot, axes

I am trying to use the plot function in R. I would like to have the values which are represented on the X-axis to be on the Y-axis and vice-versa.

Another question I have is I have a list of dates with me. I want to know how many instances of a particular date are there in the list.

How should I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

```
 plot(y, x)  # I'm guessing there is something you are not telling us.
```

In the situation where you are using the default indexing with a single "y" vector the answer would be:

```
 plot( x=y, y= 1:length(y) )  
    # This was reversed when it was posted as an edit-response to the comment.
```

2)

```
 table(dates)[as.Date("YYYY-MM-DD")] # with the obvious substitutions
```

Comment: I just have a single list. So i am currently using plot(x).

Comment: Thanks! The second answer is exactly what I wanted !